# The square keeps disappearing in the pygame

Tags: python, pygame, keydown

When you press the X key, a rectangle is about to be made, but it keeps disappearing. Is it because of code `pygame.fill(black)`?

```
if pressed[pygame.K_x]    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,yellow,(chd1,chd2,10,10))     
    chd1+=10
```

And how can I make this square fly away when I press the <kbd>x</kbd> key?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply.
Something just came up and turned on the computer.
The bottom line is that it's not solved yet.
What I want to do is press the X key once and it creates a yellow square and automatically flies to the end of the screen. Like a bullet. If you hit the X key in a row, you'll have to create a lot of yellow squares.

Comment: I understood that in order for the square to appear to move when the direction key is pressed, the screen must be constantly blacked out and the next position of the shape must be updated. But I hope that the square that comes out when you press the X key goes forward naturally like a bullet.

Answer (score 1):

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns the state of the keys. If you hold down <kbd>x</kbd>, the rectangle will be visible. When you let go of the key, the status of the key is `False"` again and the condition is no longer fulfilled. The rectangle is no longer drawn anymore and will disappear.

If you want that the rectangle will appear when <kbd>x</kbd> is pressed, then you have to set a state `draw_rect`:

```py
draw_rect = False

run = True
while run:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_x]    
        chd1+=10
        draw_rect = True
 
    screen.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,yellow,(chd1,chd2,10,10))     
    pygame.display.flip()
```